# Change Link in Workbook programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

All,

I have the following code to change a workbook's link.

`ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink "OldPath.xlsx", "NewPath.xlsx", xlLinkTypeExcelLinks`

My problem is that "NewPath.xlsx" represents a workbook that has a slightly different name for the WorkSheet Object than in OldPath.xlsx.  So, is there a way to programmatically change not just the Path associated with the Excel workbook, but also the actual object/range reference or the external link in question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just for future reference, define Names are the best way to prevent this issue in future, as it does not matter if you move cells around or rename worksheets.

Comment: If only these were my workbooks from the beginning, we wouldn't have this issue.  I'm taking a different appraoch now using OpenXML SDK, which I think will work.  Been slammed with other projects, though, so this one is kind of low priority for now.

Comment: Also, for named ranges to work, the linked workbook actually needs to be openned to refresh data.

Comment: I forgot that - good point. What about renaming the sheets from New -> Old then opening the book with links. You can then do whatever: rename the sheets back to New, or just update the values and close the source book without saving, etc...

Comment: I thought about that, and I might end up doing that if I can't get everything to work in OpenXML.  The problem is that the old file location doesn't exist anymore, so either way, I would at least need to use OpenXML to update the workbook path to a Workbook that I can actually get in and change.

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I have is a extended version of @d-stroyer solution. You need to replace part of the formulas including path to the document as well (or simply workbook reference if one is open):

```
Cells.Replace What:="C:\Users\Name\Desktop\[OldPath.xlsx]OldSheetName", _
    Replacement:="C:\Users\Name\Desktop\[NewPath.xlsx]NewSheetName", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Unfortunately, this will not work (I think, not tested) if you want to replace links in other excel elements like: series of charts, possibly data source of pivottables, etc.

Comment: You are right.  This does not work.  Also, it's a bit clunky since I would have to parse OldPath and NewPath to separate the file from the folder that contains the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Use a simple Replace statement :

```
Sub UpdateSheetName()

    Cells.Replace What:="OldSheetName", Replacement:="NewSheetName", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

If your workbook has other occurrences of the sheet name, and you don't want them to be caught by the search, use a limited range. Also, you can restrict by searching "OldSheetName!" (with the "!") and replacing by "NewSheetName!".

Comment: this doesn't make any difference to use simple line of code from the question. In both situation you get window asking for confirmation of sheet change as not recognised in the other source...