# VBA Find and replace Issue

Tags: vba, loops, excel, replace, excel-2010

I have a workbook that comes from someone else so the file path is referring to that person's local drive. So I need to replace the file path with the one in my local drive. I tried 3 methods and they all failed. Please give me some guidelines. Basically, I am trying to find a replace 2 file paths within a formula for an entire sheet (almost all the cells) (see below):

`='U:\Futochan\2012\[Futochan2012.xlsm]Counts'!E6+'U:\Futochan\2013\[Futochan2013.xlsm]Counts'!E6`

**1st Method:**
Did this manually. DAta -> Edit Links -> Change sources (Failed, keep prompted me for the links)

**2nd Method:**
VBA: Did the range.replace. It only replaced the first cell and halted.

**3rd Method:**
VBA: Did a cell by cell loop :"For each cell in range". I turned off everything. It worked but took 2 hours. :/

Please help!! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why the first method wouldn't work. Try switching to Manual calculation mode (on the Formulas tab) before doing this, then set it back to Manual and press F9 to force a recalculation.

Comment: simple `Find+Replace` could work as presented in [this simple code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17668972/2143262)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, any reason why you can't do a manual find and replace all for "U:\Futochan\2012[Futochan2012.xlsm]"? If it is just two links, and this is a one-off, this is by far the quickest approach.

For Range.replace, what was your range? If you call it on Worksheet.Cells.replace(...) it should replace all instances.

Finally, a quick approach that does not involve Range.Replace is below, but again, reinventing the wheel is a less than preferable approach :)

```
Private stringsToReplace As New Collection
Sub blah()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr
    Dim formulaCells As Range, area As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    stringsToReplace.Add Array("old1", "new1") 'add as many pairs as you like in the format of Array(oldString,newString)

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error Resume Next
    Set formulaCells = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) 'only look at formula cells for speed
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not formulaCells Is Nothing Then

        For Each area In formulaCells 'we will load into an array in memory, to prevent the horrendously slow enumeration through cells
            If area.Count = 1 Then
                area.Formula = newFormulaText(area.Formula)
            Else
                arr = area.Formula
                For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                    For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
                        arr(i, j) = newFormulaText(arr(i, j))
                    Next j
                Next i
                area.Formula = arr
            End If
        Next area

    End If

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Function newFormulaText(ByVal oldText As String) As String
    Dim oldNewPair
    Dim newText As String
    newText = oldText
    For Each oldNewPair In stringsToReplace
        newText = Replace(newText, oldNewPair(0), oldNewPair(1))
    Next oldNewPair
    newFormulaText = newText
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. Only this method fixes my problem!

Comment: Glad it helps. If it solved your issues then please mark it as the selected answer ;)